# How to locate an element and extract required text with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am using Selenium to enter data on a web page, but have run into an issue with one of the input fields. This is the HTML code causing my difficulty:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="address">Enter your address</label>
<input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="" style="font-size:1.8em;padding:15px;height:40px">
<label for="address">Enter this code: 2784873 </label>
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" value="" style="font-size:1.8em;padding:15px;height:40px">
```

I want to use Selenium to copy the numeric value after `Enter this code: 2784873` (in this case, **2784873**), which I would then enter in the input field below, but so far have been unable to figure out how to get this. I tried using `driver.find_element_by_id()` but that was unsuccessful. I also tried using xpath (which seems to me like the best approach) with:

```
codes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"page-wrapper\"]/div[2]/div[2]/center/form/div/label[2]")
```

but the value returned in `codes` is:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ae4e91d8ec7e2bc161", element="0.570523580858733-2")
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: What's the value of `codes.getText()`?

Comment: Not sure where you meant to use this. If I do `print(codes.getText()`  I get an error: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'

Comment: Thanks for the clue, figured it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-control + [for=address]').text
```

Use `replace()` to remove the `enter this code:` string if required

That is a class selector "." with adjacent sibling combinator joining to attribute = value selector. So element with attribute `for` having value `address` that is adjacent to element with class `form-control`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the clue offered by [glhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115244/glhr) above, I was able to figure this out. [glhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115244/glhr) asked what `codes.getText()` revealed, but `getText()` is for the Java version of Selenium. In this case I am using Python, so it should be `.text`:

```
codes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"page-wrapper\"]/div[2]/div[2]/center/form/div/label[2]").text
```

which for the example above returns "Enter this code: 2784873".

Problem solved, thanks!

Edit: Thanks to [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr) as well, whose solution came in just as I was writing this.

Comment: Your code is NOT going to work because you are using `find_elements` (plural) which will throw an error. Also your locator is very brittle with all the levels and indices. You should accept (and use) QHarr's answer. The locator is much less brittle and the code works.

Comment: Thanks, the `find_elements` was a typo, I actually ended up using `find_element`. However, point taken, I accepted and am using QHarr's answer. Thanks!