# Selenium extract certain value from element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, split, webdriverwait

I have a page that has code designed as given below. From this, using automation id I would like to get values '6' and 'ft' separately.

```
<span class="something" ....>
    <span abcdef automation-id="xyz"> My height is 6 ft </span>
</span>
```

I saw this question, which helps to some extent. The solution given by Qharr here makes sense.
[How to locate an element and extract required text with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715082/how-to-locate-an-element-and-extract-required-text-with-selenium-and-python)
I'm trying to find elements in a similar way by using automation id and get values '6' and 'ft' by using, maybe + operator for sibling values?

```
WebElement x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(use automation id)+ ....
```

So basically in one above the line, I would like x to capture value '6' and use a different webelement say y to capture value 'ft' in one line of code.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what the problem is.

Comment: @stuart As per your code trials`driver.find_element_by_css_selector()` and the linked discussion, I've replaced the  Java tag with Python tag. Let me know if the change is as per your requirement or else I will revert back the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to extract the phrase *`My height is 6 ft`* and then split the text/string into a list using [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp). Now you can print the desired element from the list as per their respective position as follows:

```
print("Number: " + WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@automation-id='xyz']"))).text.split()[-2])
print("Units: " + WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@automation-id='xyz']"))).text.split()[-1])
```

Console Output:

```
Number: 6
Units: ft
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
WebElement x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(use automation id)+ .... ;


String info = x.getText();

String[]y = info.split(" ");

String height = y[y.length-2];
String weightMeter = y[y.length-1];
```